# I need to control samsung Duos s 2 phone like my earlier nokia phone using pc suite

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

I need to control samsung Duos s 2(GT 7582) phone with my PC like I am having now with nokia phone using Nokia pc suite

Comment: Thanks. But, the primary question is controlling the phone after connecting to PC. Wanted to call , SMS from PC using phone w/o really touching the phone. Hope I am clear..

Answer (score 0):

I use [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid). It works pretty well for most things like sending messages, transferring files and calling, and you don't have to plug your device into your PC.